# How do you change the contents of an object in JAVA?

Tags: java, class, object

I am going through a class to learn about JAVA...

I was told to add a method (void swapNames(Greeter other)) that swaps the names of this greeter and another. Then to create two objects in the Greeter class and use the swapNames method to swap their names.

I started with ..

```
public class Greeter {

    public Greeter(String aName){
        name = aName;
    }

    public String sayHello(){
        return "Hello, " + name + "!";
    }
    private String name;

    public void swapNames(Greeter other){

    }
}
```

BUT I am getting stuck. How can I finish this "swapNames()" to change the name of the two objects?

Comment: In layman terms, what have you tried?

Comment: How would you swap content of two buckets? Easiest way is to use another bucket. Put content of bucket A in additional bucket, then from B to A, then from additional bucket to B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.name = other.name;
```

I think that should work.

Update:

I forgot you want to swap their names, so:

```
String aux = this.name;
this.name = other.getName();
other.setName(aux);
```

You will need a setName and getName methods since "name" is private.

Comment: How would this `swap` their names? Well now it just wouldn't compile in java heh.

Comment: P.S. you would still not be able to do `other.name;`

Comment: Sorry, i noticed that, fixed :)

Comment: @austinwernli What do you mean by "*you would still not be able to do `other.name;`*"? `Greeter` class have access to all its fields, regardless if they are in `this` instance, or in `other` instance.

Comment: You are correct! I was mistaken, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

```
public void swapNames(Greeter other){
    String temp = name; // holds temp for this name
    name = other.name; // begin swapping
    other.name = temp;
}
```